# What are the effects of adding EventHandler += EventHandler?

Tags: c#, .net, events, .net-3.5

I have a `SelectionChanged` event in class A that I want to relay through class B. I assumed that declaring a `SelectionChanged` event in class B and assigning this EventHandler to `A.SelectionChanged` would cause `B.SelectionChanged` to trigger whenever `A.SelectionChanged` was triggered - this turned out to be false.

To be more clear, some code:

```
class A
{
   public event EventHandler SelectionChanged;

   public void TriggerSelectionChanged()
   {
      if (SelectionChanged != null) SelectionChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
   }
}

class B
{
   private A _a = new A();

   public A A { get { return _a; } }

   public event EventHandler SelectionChanged;

   public B()
   {
      A.SelectionChanged += SelectionChanged;
   }

   public static void Test()
   {
      B relayer = new B();
      bool wasRelayed = false;
      relayer.SelectionChanged += delegate { wasRelayed = true; };
      relayer.A.TriggerSelectionChanged();

      System.Console.WriteLine("Relayed: {0}", wasRelayed);
   }
}
```

This prints out "Relayed: false".

What are the effects of adding an EventHandler to another EventHandler?

**EDIT:**
Note! I'm aware of that a solution to this is to relay the event through an delegate, function etc etc, but I'm mostly interrested in knowning what the effects of this code is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this is an effect from EventHandler being a Delegate. This class implements operator += through (or so I assume) using [Delegate.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.combine%28v=VS.90%29.aspx). The documentation of this function reads

> Concatenates the invocation lists of the specified multicast (combinable) delegates.

What happens is that all handlers assigned to the EventHandler on the right side are added to the EventHandler on the left. In this case there's zero handlers so nothing happens. However, if the order of things are changed such that `B.SelectionChanged` is assigned before `B.SelectionChanged` is connected to `A.SelectionChanged` things are hooked up correctly. However, removing an handler from B does not remove it from A so doing this should be highly frawned upon.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing in your code that 'connects' the invocation of `B.SelectionChanged` to `A.SelectionChanged`. Therefore, when you fire a `SelectionChanged` on `A`, your delegate that handles `SelectionChanged` on `B` is not invoked.

I think what you want is for your event on B to acts as an adapter on the event that A exposes? If this is the case, you will need to write your own `add` / `remove` logic. See the following:

[Events + Adapter Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676437/events-adapter-pattern)

Another example of add / remove:

[C#: event with explicity add/remove != typical event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015166/c-event-with-explicity-add-remove-typical-event)

Comment: I forgot to add the constructor connecting B to A, edited the question.

Answer (score 2):

In this case B's SelectionChanged and A's SelectionChanged are not related.

If you were to make B inherit from A and remove the second declaration on B then this would work.

```
class A
{
   public EventHandler SelectionChanged;

   public void TriggerSelectionChanged()
   {
      if (SelectionChanged != null) SelectionChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
   }
}

class B : A
{
   public static void Test()
   {
      B relayer = new B();
      bool wasRelayed = false;
      relayer.SelectionChanged += delegate { wasRelayed = true; };
      relayer.TriggerSelectionChanged();

      System.Console.WriteLine("Relayed: {0}", wasRelayed);
   }
}
```

Or you can pump your messages through...

```
class A
{
   public EventHandler SelectionChanged;

   public void TriggerSelectionChanged()
   {
      if (SelectionChanged != null) SelectionChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
   }
}

class B
{
   public B()
   {
     this._a.SelectionChanged += (o, s) => 
     {
       if(this.SelectionChanged != null) { this.SelectionChange(o, s); }
     };
   }




private A _a = new A();

   public A A { get { return _a; } }

   public EventHandler SelectionChanged;

   public static void Test()
   {
      B relayer = new B();
      bool wasRelayed = false;
      relayer.SelectionChanged += delegate { wasRelayed = true; };
      relayer.A.TriggerSelectionChanged();
      System.Console.WriteLine("Relayed: {0}", wasRelayed);
   }
```

}

Comment: I think the OP wants B to contain A, not extend it.

Comment: @larsm, I've added similar code to do what you're trying. I don't think you can do what you're trying in your modified code, think it needs to be a delegate.

Comment: @Ian: that's my fallback. However, I'm mostly interrested in the effects of EventHandler += EventHandler, not the other solutions.

Comment: @larsm: Sorry, I getcha. +1 for your own answer